# How can i add smtp code

Tags: php

First of all, I'm new here and PHP

My question is about Smtp support. my hosting need smtp support. I didn't add it. I read a lot post but my knowledge basic. How can I add smtp code in this file please help me

```
<?php
  //start a session -- needed for Securimage Captcha check
  session_start();

  //add you e-mail address here
  define("MY_EMAIL", "sss@sss.com,sss@gmail.com");

  /**
   * Sets error header and json error message response.
   *
   * @param  String $messsage error message of response
   * @return void
   */
  function errorResponse ($messsage) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die(json_encode(array('message' => $messsage)));
  }

  /**
   * Return a formatted message body of the form:
   * Name: <name of submitter>
   * Comment: <message/comment submitted by user>
   *
   * @param String $name     name of submitter
   * @param String $messsage message/comment submitted
   */
  function setMessageBody ($name, $phone, $email, $message) {
    $message_body .= "Name: " . $name."\n\n";
    $message_body .= "Phone: " . $phone."\n\n";
    $message_body .= "Email: " . $email."\n\n";
    $message_body .= "Message:" . $message."\n\n";
    return $message_body;
  }

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];  
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $message = $_POST['message'];

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  //do some simple validation. this should have been validated on the client-side also
  if (empty($email) || empty($message)) {
    errorResponse('Email or message is empty.');
  }

  //do Captcha check, make sure the submitter is not a robot:)...
  include_once './vender/securimage/securimage.php';
  $securimage = new Securimage();
  if (!$securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])) {
    errorResponse('Invalid Security Code');
  }
//try to send the message
 if(mail(MY_EMAIL, "Feedback Form Results", setMessageBody($_POST["name"], $_POST["phone"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"]), "From:$email")) {
 echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your message was successfully submitted.'));

 } else {
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
 echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Unexpected error while attempting to send e-mail.'));
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding smtp code (and where)? What is the current output of your script and what is the desired one?

Comment: Use some library like SwiftMailer to send email using SMTP. Also make sure your PHP has SMTP support (look in phpinfo(), must recompile PHP if missing).

Comment: you try solution at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. This is solution have full documents to dev.

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html. Not checked it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Use php mailer for smtp https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/. this library has smtp code default and given so many examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = "mailserver.blahblah.com";
$username = "smtp_username";
$password = "smtp_password";

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host,
                                     'auth' => true,
                                     'username' => $username,
                                     'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```